# AND and OR logical operators in Scheme

Tags: scheme, logical-operators

I have a conditional, and I want to test to see if two things are true.  How can I do an equivalent of `&&` or `||` from Java in Scheme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(and (equals? var1 var2) (equals? var3 var4))
```

Answer (score 4):

Also note that not only does:

```
(and (equals? var1 var2) (equals? var3 var4))
```

work, but also:

```
(and (equals? var1 var2) (equals? var3 var4) (equals? var5 var6))
```

vs

```
(and (and (equals? var1 var2) (equals? var3 var4)) (equals? var5 var6))
```

(and ...) and (or ...) take any number of arguments.

Answer (score 3):

It's important to note that `and` and `or` don't return `#t`, but rather, the truthy value for which the condition was satisfied: either the last true value in `and` or the first true value in `or`.

```
(and 1 2) => 2
(and #f 2) => #f
(and #t 6) => 6
(or 1 2) => 1
(or #f #f 0 #f) => 0
```